# which relationship is this, one to one from one side and many to one from other side

Tags: c#, java, .net, database, domain-driven-design

I want to know how to properly set relationship in this scenario

There are `Article` and `Location` entitites.

In any point of time one Article can be at only one location, and looking from the other side one location can hold one or more articles.

So what kind of relationship is this?

from one side is one to one and from other side is many to one.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ONE location can have MANY articles, that is a one to many relationship.

The `ONE` on the Location side of the relationship means that all articles only can have one location, the 'MANY' on the Article side, means that any location can have many articles.